# Cordova Android Push Plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create push notification for my cordova project. I followed the tutorial from this link http://devgirl.org/2012/10/25/tutorial-android-push-notifications-with-phonegap/ and created the plugin and I see the FCM is not sending back the registration id. I have added sender id in my application. Please help me to get this done. Thanks in advance.

GCMIntentService.java

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("GCMIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {

        Log.v(TAG, "onRegistered: "+ regId);

        JSONObject json;

        try
        {
            json = new JSONObject().put("event", "registered");
            json.put("regid", regId);

            Log.v(TAG, "onRegistered: " + json.toString());

            // Send this JSON data to the JavaScript application above EVENT should be set to the msg type
            // In this case this is the registration ID
            PushPlugin.sendJavascript( json );

        }
        catch( JSONException e)
        {
            // No message to the user is sent, JSON failed
            Log.e(TAG, "onRegistered: JSON exception");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnregistered(Context context, String regId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onUnregistered - regId: " + regId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

        // Extract the payload from the message
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {

            // if we are in the foreground, just surface the payload, else post it to the statusbar
            if (PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
                extras.putBoolean("foreground", true);
                 createNotification(context, extras);
                PushPlugin.sendExtras(extras);
            }
            else {
                extras.putBoolean("foreground", false);

                // Send a notification if there is a message
                if (extras.getString("message") != null && extras.getString("message").length() != 0) {
                    createNotification(context, extras);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
    {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String appName = getAppName(this);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        int defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

        if (extras.getString("defaults") != null) {
            try {
                defaults = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("defaults"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setDefaults(defaults)
                .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)

                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
                .setContentText(extras.getString("title"))
                .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        String message = extras.getString("message");
        if (message != null) {
            mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
        }

        String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");
        if (msgcnt != null) {
            mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
        }

        int notId = 0;

        try {
            notId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("notId"));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID" + e.getMessage());
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, notId, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private static String getAppName(Context context)
    {
        CharSequence appName = 
                context
                    .getPackageManager()
                    .getApplicationLabel(context.getApplicationInfo());

        return (String)appName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onError - errorId: " + errorId);
    }

}
```

PushPlugin.Java

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public  class PushPlugin extends Plugin {
    public static final String TAG = "PushPlugin";
    public static final String REGISTER = "register";
    public static final String UNREGISTER = "unregister";
    public static final String EXIT = "exit";

    private static CordovaWebView gWebView;
    private static String gECB;
    private static String gSenderID;
    private static Bundle gCachedExtras = null;
    private static boolean gForeground = false;


    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String CallbackContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean result = false;

        Log.v(TAG, "execute: action=" + action);
        if (REGISTER.equals(action)) {

            Log.v(TAG, "execute: data=" + data.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jo = data.getJSONObject(0);

                gWebView = this.webView;
                Log.v(TAG, "execute: jo=" + jo.toString());

                gECB = (String) jo.get("ecb");
                gSenderID = (String) jo.get("senderID");

                Log.v(TAG, "execute: ECB=" + gECB + " senderID=" + gSenderID);

                GCMRegistrar.register(this.cordova.getActivity(), gSenderID);
                result = true;
            //  callbackContext.success();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "execute: Got JSON Exception " + e.getMessage());
                result = false;
            //  callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            }

            if ( gCachedExtras != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "sending cached extras");
                sendExtras(gCachedExtras);
                gCachedExtras = null;
            }
        }else if (UNREGISTER.equals(action)) {

             GCMRegistrar.unregister(this.cordova.getActivity());

            Log.v(TAG, "UNREGISTER");
            result = true;
        //  callbackContext.success();
        } else {
            result = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid action : " + action);
            //callbackContext.error("Invalid action : " + action);
        }
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
        //return null;
    }

    public static void sendExtras(Bundle extras)
    {
        if (extras != null) {
            if (gECB != null && gWebView != null) {
                sendJavascript(convertBundleToJson(extras));
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "sendExtras: caching extras to send at a later time.");
                gCachedExtras = extras;
            }
        }
    }
    private static JSONObject convertBundleToJson(Bundle extras)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject json;
            json = new JSONObject().put("event", "message");

            JSONObject jsondata = new JSONObject();
            Iterator<String> it = extras.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                String key = it.next();
                Object value = extras.get(key);

                // System data from Android
                if (key.equals("from") || key.equals("collapse_key"))
                {
                    json.put(key, value);
                }
                else if (key.equals("foreground"))
                {
                    json.put(key, extras.getBoolean("foreground"));
                }
                else if (key.equals("coldstart"))
                {
                    json.put(key, extras.getBoolean("coldstart"));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Maintain backwards compatibility
                    if (key.equals("message") || key.equals("msgcnt") || key.equals("soundname"))
                    {
                        json.put(key, value);
                    }

                    if ( value instanceof String ) {
                    // Try to figure out if the value is another JSON object

                        String strValue = (String)value;
                        if (strValue.startsWith("{")) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(strValue);
                                jsondata.put(key, json2);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                jsondata.put(key, value);
                            }
                            // Try to figure out if the value is another JSON array
                        }
                        else if (strValue.startsWith("["))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                JSONArray json2 = new JSONArray(strValue);
                                jsondata.put(key, json2);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                jsondata.put(key, value);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            jsondata.put(key, value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } // while
            json.put("payload", jsondata);

            Log.v(TAG, "extrasToJSON: " + json.toString());

            return json;
        }
        catch( JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "extrasToJSON: JSON exception");
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void sendJavascript(JSONObject _json) {
        String _d = "javascript:" + gECB + "(" + _json.toString() + ")";
        Log.v(TAG, "sendJavascript: " + _d);

        if (gECB != null && gWebView != null) {
            gWebView.sendJavascript(_d);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isInForeground()
    {
      return gForeground;
    }

    public static boolean isActive()
    {
        return gWebView != null;
    }

}
```

PushHandlerActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class PushHandlerActivity extends Activity
{
    private static String TAG = "PushHandlerActivity"; 

    /*
     * this activity will be started if the user touches a notification that we own. 
     * We send it's data off to the push plugin for processing.
     * If needed, we boot up the main activity to kickstart the application. 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");

        boolean isPushPluginActive = PushPlugin.isActive();
        processPushBundle(isPushPluginActive);

        finish();

        if (!isPushPluginActive) {
            forceMainActivityReload();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Takes the pushBundle extras from the intent, 
     * and sends it through to the PushPlugin for processing.
     */
    private void processPushBundle(boolean isPushPluginActive)
    {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            Bundle originalExtras = extras.getBundle("pushBundle");

            originalExtras.putBoolean("foreground", false);
            originalExtras.putBoolean("coldstart", !isPushPluginActive);

            PushPlugin.sendExtras(originalExtras);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Forces the main activity to re-launch if it's unloaded.
     */
    private void forceMainActivityReload()
    {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());           
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
  }

}
```

Manifeast file

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission
        android:name="MyPackageName".push.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <activity android:name="MyPackageName".push.PushHandlerActivity"/>
        <receiver android:name="MyPackageName".push.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="MyPackageName".push" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

      <service android:name="MyPackageName".push.GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: That's a really old blog.

First, if you're running in an emulator, FCM will simply return a nasty "BLACKLISTED" message.  It doesn't mean your app is blacklisted, just that FCM won't acknowledge an emulator.

Second, you need to post some code.

Third, you didn't tell us if you're testing on iOS or Android.

Comment: Hi I have added my code. Its an android app and i am running directly into my samsung device. I have added GCM jar file in lib folder and added to my buld path also . Thanks in advance

Comment: Creating your own push plugin is a tedious task. There are so many changes to accommodate that you'll spend countless hours debugging,  fixing and releasing new versions (weekly).  I would suggest you use the existing plugin-push at levels 2.0.0 or greater. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push